# How to use Android Galaxy Tab emulator?

Tags: android

I am having a problem in hadling the galaxy tablet emulator whenever I'll run my application and the tablet launcnh then it will not shown any option to open my appliction or goto the menu! It will shows the normal home not having any menu kind of option. I am sending you the screen shot of emulator.Plz help I try a lot to handle this but no clue how to use.....

[Android Galaxy Tab Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMvNb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit after looking at picture: Wait--first of all.  You know you have to drag that slider thing across the screen to get started, right?  After that--

I'm not sure about that specific one, but I did notice some general weirdness with the Android emulators.  I found a pattern that makes them work--be patient and deliberate.

First restart all your stuff--heck restart your computer to be safe.

Launch eclipse.  Start a debug session with the emulator.  wait.  WAIT... wait... Might be 30 seconds, might be 3 minutes, who knows.

Eventually the emulator should come up and, behold, maybe it works!

If so--here's the trick--never ever shut it down.  Leave it up the whole time you are debugging.  It will load your app in seconds and run it like a champ.  Shut it down and you will have to restart eclipse to get it to work correctly again.

Between the long wait time and that bug I've seen people extremely frustrated (including myself).

If this isn't your problem--sorry, worth a shot.